# C# login code not working

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a login code by using cross-table parameterised SQL. The code is not working and I do not know why.

C# Code:

```
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=project;username=root;password=***;"))
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT  * FROM student, teacher 
     WHERE student.username = @userName AND student.password = @passWord 
     AND teacher.username = @teacherUser AND teacher.password = @teacherPass;");

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textboxUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", texBoxPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherUser", textBoxTeacherUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherPass", textBoxTeacherPassword.Text);
    connection.Open();    
    MySqlDataReader DBReader;
    DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    int check = 0;
    while (DBReader.Read())
    {
        check = check + 1;
    }
    if (check == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Login Successfull");
        this.Hide();
        Test ss = new Test();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect.  Try Again please");
    }
    connection.Close();

}
```

I want it to give access to the student or teacher (different users) with the correct username and password. However I keep getting the same output:

> Username or Password Incorrect. Try Again Please

```
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM student, teacher WHERE (student.username = @userName AND student.password = @passWord) OR (teacher.username = @teacherUser AND teacher.password = @teacherPass);");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", textboxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", texBoxPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherUser", textboxUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherPass", texBoxPassword.Text);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader DBReader;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            DBReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int check = 0;
            while (DBReader.Read())
            {
                var teacherLogin = DBReader.GetString("teacher.username");
                var teacherPass = DBReader.GetString("teacher.password");
                var studentLogin = DBReader.GetString("student.username");
                var studentPass = DBReader.GetString("student.password");

                if (teacherLogin == textboxUsername.Text && teacherPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull!");

                    this.Hide();
                    Registration ss = new Registration();
                    ss.Show();
                }
                else if (studentLogin == texBoxPassword.Text && studentPass == texBoxPassword.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Login Successfull");

                    this.Hide();
                    Test ss = new Test();
                    ss.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect.  Try Again please");
                }

            }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find specified column in results: teacher.username

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to use OR condition in your sql query?

```
SELECT * FROM student, teacher WHERE (student.username = @userName AND student.password = @passWord) OR (teacher.username = @teacherUser AND teacher.password = @teacherPass)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to edit the code so that : if the teacher logs in - send teacher to teacher form. else if student logins - send student to student form?

Comment: in your DBReader.Read() read login and password and validate it one more time in c# code

Comment: I am not really familiar with .Read.   can you show me a sample code to get me started please?

Comment: Should be something like this
            while (DBReader.Read())
            {
                var teacherLogin = DBReader.GetString("Name of your columt in database");
                var teacherPass = DBReader.GetString("Name of your columt in database");
                if (teacherLogin == yourLogin && teacherPass == yourPass)
                {
                    //it is teacher
                }
                // add the same logic for usual user
            }

Comment: do I need to specify the table because column name "username" is in both teacher and student

Comment: look at the question I edited with the code: it says student.username / teacher.username doesn't exist. Error

Comment: I think it make sense to change your sql query like: select username, isTeacher = 1 from teacher where teacher.username = teacherUser AND teacher.password = teacherPass union select username, isTeacher = 0 from student where student.username = userName AND student.password = passWord

Comment: and after in reader you can get 'isTeacher' and check if it is true or false

Answer (score 0):

If you change the select statement to something like below, this will work -

```
 SELECT teacher.username as `teacher.username`,teacher.password as `teacher.password`,student.username as `student.username`,student.password as `student.password` FROM student, teacher WHERE (student.username = @userName AND student.password = @passWord) OR (teacher.username = @teacherUser AND teacher.password = @teacherPass);"
```